# Using custom DateTime Binder in Web Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to register my custom datetime binder so I can parse datetime coming to API in custom format.

I tried to register my custom `DateTimeModelBinder` but it does not get hit and debug point does not come to it and it does not trigger. below is different ways I tried in global asax and also in WebApiConfig.

**Custom Binder Registration**

```
  protected void Application_Start()
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = false;

            config.BindParameter(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());
            config.BindParameter(typeof(DateTime?), new DateTimeModelBinder());

            //ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), new DateTimeModelBinderProvider());


        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

    }
```

**Web Api Action**

```
 [Route("")]
        public DataActionResponse PostEvent(EventBindingModel model)
        {
            return _eventService
                    .Create(model, CompanyId, UserId)
                    .CreateDataActionResponseSuccess();
        }
```

**DateTimeModelBinder.cs**

```
 public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var dateToParse = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName).AttemptedValue;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dateToParse))
                return false;

            bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName));


            bindingContext.Model = ParseDateTime(dateToParse);
            if (bindingContext.Model != null)
                return true;


            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(
                key: bindingContext.ModelName,
                errorMessage: $"Invalid date format for {bindingContext.ModelName}:{dateToParse}. Should be in 'MM/dd/yyyy' OR 'MM/dd/yyyyTHH:mm' format.");
            return false;
        }

        public DateTime? ParseDateTime(string dateToParse)
        {
            var enUs = new CultureInfo("en-US");

            foreach (var format in SellutionConstants.Globals.BindingDateTimeFormat)
            {
                DateTime validDate;

                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(
                    s: dateToParse,
                    format: format,
                    provider: enUs,
                    style: DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces,
                    result: out validDate))
                {
                    return validDate;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

**EventBindingModel.cs**

```
   public class EventBindingModel
    {
        public int? EventId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `SimpleModelBinderProvider` class

```
var provider = new SimpleModelBinderProvider(typeof(DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());
config.Services.Insert(typeof(ModelBinderProvider), 0, provider);
```